What to do when someone approves a bad question in the Staging Ground
I'm noticing that a lot of questions are approved in the Staging Ground while still in a (somewhat) poor state. For example:

I'm having trouble... has an image of console output, does not contain an MRE, and links to GitHub instead of providing sufficient code.
Cant activate virtual... has an image of console output.
How to get... has an error that doesn't match the code sample (read: not an MRE) and doesn't explain why the current solution is unsatisfactory.
terraform GCP cloud... could use some formatting for both the code and error message.
Can someone help... contains data as an image instead of a table and doesn't clearly explain the desired output.

So far, I've just  been treating their graduated counterparts as I do any other question - flag as "Needs improvement," leave a comment for how it can be improved, and downvote, to the extent that each of those is applicable.
Is there anything else I should do for Staging Ground questions in particular?

One could say that questions being flagged/closed after being graduated is a signal that the site can automatically detect. I am not necessarily of the opinion that it is "you" (meaning us) who should be doing more at this stage. Let them measure the ineffectiveness first.

"Pity" I don't do any 'SG' Reviews anymore until the "Show tag user guidance in tag hover" Setting has been activated, "I'm having trouble...[...]" or "Can someone help...[...]" in the Title were exactly the kind of Qt's I was tackling from the 'SG', => decent=descriptive Title first, and then assess "the rest"...

What you can do
For the posts themselves, treat them like other bad quality posts and close them if applicable. The main mechanisms to deal with/remove these questions are on the main site.
Note that you can't expect questions coming out of the Staging Ground to be high-quality. But the author should make it clear what's asked and it should be on-topic on Stack Overflow. If it needs a subject-matter expert to judge whether the question is ok or needs details, it's ok to be published.
For reviewers you have a few options:

If you have reason to believe the reviewer acted in good faith but doesn't understand or overlooked something, you could try to contact the reviewer directly via Chat and tell them that it isn't really a good question. You can find the chat profile of a user by taking the profile URL and prepending it with the chat. subdomain. Note that this may not work for all users (I think you can't create a chatroom with a user if they never used Chat).
If it's just a single post from the reviewer and their other reviews look good (or it's their only review), you can't really do much. Just go on.
If you can see a pattern of the reviewer approving bad questions (you can use the review history and search for reviews of the user - I wrote a user script for this), you can raise a custom flag in one of the Staging Ground posts they reviewed. Please explain why you think their reviews are bad in some form and maybe also link to some examples (you can use [Q](/q/<question ID>) which works with SG posts for links if you reach the character limit of the flag dialog).

A special case would be obvious spam (I haven't seen that being approved until now Nevermind, after looking at my pending flags, I did come across that). These posts shouldn't be posted to the main site. In that case, I would flag the published post as spam and raise a custom flag on the SG post to inform mods that the reviewer let through the said obvious spam since they are probably not really taking attention while reviewing.
Your linked questions
Let's look at the specific cases you linked. I am not including specific post links to not have too much of a Meta effect. Note that these are my opinions:

In the first case, I can find 5 approvals from the reviewer and no other Staging Ground review actions. Out of these, one question doesn't really explain the problem, one has an image of data that doesn't even have image formatting (the one you linked), one is fine IMO but could be better written, one where I am not sure what exactly the OP wants and one is asking about errors without stating what the errors are. I think this reviewer may not understand the Staging Ground and/or the expected quality level on Stack Overflow. I guess you could try to contact people like that in Chat.
In the second case, I found two other reviews from that reviewer which are both "Requires Major Changes" and seem reasonable. I don't see any action needed regarding this reviewer.
The third user approved 4 posts in the Staging Ground. The one you linked mostly looks fine for non-SMEs and I think the error does even match the first code sample (with sklearn's train_test_split)). One was (IMO rightfully) marked as off-topic before and still approved for some reason (before being closed on the main site), one should be focused more on a single problem and one has formatting issues in a way the reviewer should have definitely seen. Similar to the first case, I think this reviewer probably doesn't know what we are expecting of reviewers and it might be good to inform them.
The fourth user approved the question you linked (which I think isn't that bad apart from formatting issues) and voted 4 other SG posts as off-topic so think there's anything to do regarding that reviewer.
For the last user, I agree that this question shouldn't have been published but the reviewer didn't review any other questions. They might just found the question and clicked a button not really understanding it. I don't think it's worth doing anything here as they just (wrongly) approved a single question which can happen.

All in all, these reviewers don't seem enough of a problem that I think you'd need to flag it. There are some bad reviews but IMO there isn't much of a point in going after people who don't do many reviews anyway.
For the above, I scanned 50 pages of review history so there may be some older posts I overlooked.
The real problem
Unfortunately, there are many reviewers who don't understand the Staging Ground and the Staging Ground is not explaining how exactly posts should be reviewed. Reviewer onboarding has been improved but it is still lacking. It doesn't explain contain the information from the reviewer guidelines, the importance of "Requires Major Changes" (and that it should be preferred over the off-topic option in most cases) and there is nothing showing reviewers what is actually expected from them.

So sending Terminators is not the recommended course of action. Well shoot. I'm in a bit of trouble now, aren't I?

They probably didn't have malicious intent so I wouldn't recommend that. But I guess you are only in trouble if someone can prove you did ;)

The fourth question seems to have been improved, and is probably fine now (but I am not an SME there).

"There are some bad reviews but IMO there isn't much of a point in going after people who don't do many reviews anyway." - right now, I feel like we're still at a stage where basically nobody has actually done "many" reviews. I am apparently the 25th to receive the "Instructor" badge, and 6 of those are from the beta. That compares to nearly half a million users with the required reputation total.

Yes, I don't really see many active reviewers but if someone reviews a single question, not much can be done tbh. Also, when saying "many" reviews, I mean enough that you can see an actual pattern.

If you have a good incentive for active reviewers, I would be interested in seeing it (e.g. as a [feature-request]).
